# How to write a run script to unzip file in the project directory?

Tags: ios, xcode, run-script

I need to create a run script that will un-zip a file a in the project source code directory and replace the existing files.
My requirement in details is like this. I have **aa.framework** and **bb.bundle** in a zip file. Zip file is in the source code directory. Now, at the run time (Each time compile the app) I want to up-zip the zip file and replace existing aa.framework file bb.bundle file with the un-zipped files.

Please help me to write a run script to do this if this is doable.

Comment: Why does this need doing each build? If it's for security then complex != secure.

Comment: Actually reason is, when my client download the source code from the svn to a Windows computer, those aa.framework and bb.bundle files get corrupted. I don't know the reason why. So, I want to zip those two files and up-zip then replace at the compilation.

Comment: Well I'm afraid to say that if files are getting corrupted and no-one knows why, then more problems are on there way.  Solve the problem rather than working around it.

Comment: Let's forget about the corrupted file. I want to know, can we un-zipped a zip file using xcode Run script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the path to to your project from the environment variable `PROJECT_DIR`. So you just call the `zip` and `unzip` commands.

```
unzip "${PROJECT_DIR}/yourzip.zip"
```